# bootstrap icons don't show in production server

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I made an asp.net MVC web page using twitter bootstrap. In some parts of my web, I use boostrapt icons. In my test server (local IIS) work's fine but in production server, icons draws wrong.

**Bad:**

[image]

**Ok:**

[image]

```
<button class="btn <%if(item.EsFavorita) {%>btn-warning<%} %>" 
id="<%= item.IdNoticia %>" onclick="InsertarNoticiaFavorita(this);return false;">
<i class="<%if(!item.EsFavorita) {%>icon-star-empty<% } 
else{%>icon-white icon-star<%} %>"></i>Favorito </button>
```

What could be the cause?

Edit:
from what I have seen, is a problem with version. "min" of css boostrapt, not load the files of the icons, but it's not that.

Comment: you need to allow public access to those images or upload them somewhere else

Comment: Edited with new image example

Comment: Do you get any errors? And show the markup of these buttons, please.

Comment: @user2136283 you can edit your question to add additional remarks/code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native bootstrap icons, this may be caused because of missing image files.
Please check that all the required png files are there.

** And i highly recommend u to use one of the bootstrap font icons like : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ :)

Comment: also dont forget to include bootstrap css files in your page header.

Comment: image files are ok and uploaded in production server, and css files are ok too, the rest of styles works all right